# How to display HTML inside text area using Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that questions about this topic exist, but i would like to know if anyone knows a solution for rails :)

I'm using a text_area_tag helper, and the contents that i want to display contain HTML tags.. any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an "escape" option in the `text_area_tag` method.
By default it's set to true. If you don't wish to escape the content, you can define it to false.

```
<%= text_area_tag :tag_name, 'The content', :escape => false %>
```

Comment: Mm.. I was actually using that option but it did not solve my problem.....

:(

I'm starting to think in embedding the html inside an iframe or something like that....